# Compare two set and remove common items

Tags: java

I have two sets which contain some elements as object. I want to remove common element from the set. How can I remove common elements from set?

```
Set<AcceptorInventory> updateList = new HashSet<AcceptorInventory>();
Set<AcceptorInventory> saveList = new HashSet<AcceptorInventory>();
```

Both sets have some items, the `saveList` have duplicated items & I wish to remove duplicated items from `saveList`. I tried with `foreach` loop, but it did not work.

**Sample output:**

```
save 5
save 20
save 50
save 10
update 5
update 10
update 20
```

AcceptorInventory Hashcode and equals

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + count;
    result = prime * result
            + ((currency == null) ? 0 : currency.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((date == null) ? 0 : date.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    result = prime * result + (isCleared ? 1231 : 1237);
    result = prime * result
            + ((kioskMachine == null) ? 0 : kioskMachine.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((time == null) ? 0 : time.hashCode());
    long temp;
    temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(total);
    result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    AcceptorInventory other = (AcceptorInventory) obj;
    if (count != other.count)
        return false;
    if (currency == null) {
        if (other.currency != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!currency.equals(other.currency))
        return false;
    if (date == null) {
        if (other.date != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!date.equals(other.date))
        return false;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    if (isCleared != other.isCleared)
        return false;
    if (kioskMachine == null) {
        if (other.kioskMachine != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!kioskMachine.equals(other.kioskMachine))
        return false;
    if (time == null) {
        if (other.time != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!time.equals(other.time))
        return false;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(total) != Double
            .doubleToLongBits(other.total))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Have you overriden the `equals` and `hashCode` methods? Otherwise unless the lists contain the same Object reference, you will not be able to remove them.

Comment: i have added both equals and hashcode ,but not working

Answer (score 2):

```
updateList.removeAll(saveList);
```

would remove from `updateList` all the elements of `saveList`.

If you also want to remove from `saveList` the elements of `updateList`, you'll have to create a copy of one of the sets first :

```
Set<AcceptorInventory> copyOfUpdateList = new HashSet<>(updateList);
updateList.removeAll (saveList);
saveList.removeAll (copyOfUpdateList);
```

Note that in order for your `AcceptorInventory` to function properly as an element of a `HashSet` it must override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods, and any two `AcceptorInventory` which are equal must have the same `hashCode`.

Comment: @tyson It works for me when I test it on a `Set<Integer>`. Perhaps your `AcceptorInventory` doesn't override `equals` and `hashCode` properly.

Comment: i have tested with both integer and string,its working fine.But it doesnot work on using AcceptorInventory.

Comment: @tyson See my edit. You must override `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: i have added both equals and hashcode ,but not working

Answer (score 2):

You can remove common items from current saveList using

```
saveList.removeAll(updateList);
```

Comment: List of items remove from list use removeAll or remove item by iterating that list

Comment: if one of set is null how do you deal with that